# Как в WooCommerce по id заказа узнать номер телефона клиента?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

В functions.php прописываю свою функцию. В неё есть `$order_id`. Как вызвать данные по заказу? (email, номер телефона, номер заказа, id клиента)

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$user_id = $order->user_id;
$email = $order->billing_email;
$phone = $order->billing_phone;
```

Comment: Я так понимаю что в переменной $order есть все эти данные. Но вопрос как из правильно извлечь. Это работает `$name = $order->last_name.' '.$order->first_name;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы же ответили на свой вопрос.

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$user_id = $order->user_id; // id пользователя
$email = $order->billing_email; // email
$phone = $order->billing_phone; // телефон
```

В переменной phone содержится телефон